# Could somebody explain this function I've accidentally written ("Any" keyword)?

Tags: java, syntax, keyword

I have been writing a small java application which uses Serialization/Deserialization to save/load ArrayLists. I had written the following function which takes a file path and deserializes the objects within it:

```
private Object deserialize(String fileName)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName))) {
            return ois.readObject();
        }
}
```

Since this function returns an Object type, I would then have to cast it to an ArrayList like this:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = (ArrayList<String>)deserialize("test.file");
```

*(The line above would have to be surrounded by a try/catch statement, but I did not include it here for the sake of readability)*

That process worked fine for me, however I wanted to try and see if I could edit the code to a point where I wouldn't have to cast the object myself, and so I, quite jokingly, typed **Any** as the return type of my function, and the compiler didn't complain. I then changed my function to the following, and to my surprise it actually worked!

```
private <Any> Any deserialize(String fileName)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName))) {
            return (Any)ois.readObject();
        }
}
```

When using this function, I no longer need to cast it's return value to an ArrayList, and can instead simply use:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = deserialize("test.file");
```

A part of me wants to just roll with this whole thing and just use the function without questioning how it works, but I know I'll have trouble doing this.

**Could somebody please explain why this function works the way it does, or paraphrase just explain the *Any* keyword, as I have honestly never seen it before.**

Comment: `Any` here is simply a generic type variable, not a keyword. It's no different than if you used `T`, `V`, `RESULT`, or whatever. In other words, you've made the method generic and have made the cast at the call site _implicit_.

Comment: But it will only always work if the inferred type at the call site is `Object`. Otherwise, you could get a `ClassCastException`, if the read object isn't of the inferred type.

Comment: See http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/TypeParameterUnusedInFormals for an explanation of why this use of generics is not such a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Any` isn't a keyword in Java. The key thing to notice here is the `<Any>` after the access modifier. This is the method's generic specification - the method is generalized with a type parameter called `Any` (which you then use for casting in the method body), and when you call the method, Java will [infer the return type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html).

But there's nothing special about the word "Any". You could have used "T" or "SomeType" or even "SpongeBob" to the same effect.

Comment: Plus 1 for SpongeBob

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I am familiar with generics, but I was not in the proper mindset to realize that the "Any" was a parameter, and instead believed it to be a keyword. I suppose that explains why I wasn't able to find any documentation on the "Any" keyword, because it doesn't even exist!